# SQL Query for deleting records from multiple databases in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to delete any WP user over the ID of 1

I have

```
DELETE FROM `wp_users` WHERE ID>1;
```

It works on a single database, but I want it run on every database in one go.

Is there a way to do this please?

Comment: Are you using `MySQL`?

Comment: Are you really asking about multiple **databases** or just multiple **tables** inside the same database?

Comment: Multiple database#

Comment: Mysql within PHP my admin

Comment: Could do this from the command line

Comment: You can prefix with database name: DELETE FROM \`mydb\`.\`wp_users\`... But only if user has rights